# OS Python : Open an External Excel File

Tags: python, excel, operating-system, os.system

I need to open an excel file with os. I know it's pretty easy as;

```
import os
os.system("start EXCEL.EXE file.xlsx")
```

However, name of my file varies depending on my py file.

I defined a variable called "fileopenerfullname" and it is the name of the file i want to open.

But how can i insert "fileopenerfullname" variable in os.SYSTEM("start EXCEL ......")?

I tried very much including

```
os.system("start EXCEL.EXE fileopenerfullname")
```

Does not work.

I will be glad if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Use formatted strings:

```
os.system(f"start EXCEL.EXE {fileopenerfullname}")
```

but don't forget your `fileopenerfullname` should include the extension .xlsx at the end.

Comment: I've already added .xlsx end of it, tried your command and it worked, thank you very much! The formatted strings rocks :)

Comment: No problem, Have a nice day!